# Integrating Yii2 and Wordpress

Tags: php, customization

I am trying to integrate Wordpress and Yii2. I would like to reuse the Wordpress theme view, and use the actions of the Yii2 controller.
If there is anyone who has integrated in the past Yii2 with Wordpress could he/she show me the basic steps to do that?

Comment: Probably you may want to use the yii2-wordpress extension: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

To integrate with wordpress you need to fully execute wordpress. At this point the added value of having yet another framework is probably zero as it will be easier to just do whatever you need in wordpress over the effort of integration, an effort you might need to keep doing on every new release of wordpress.

There are probably some edge cases in which it can make sense, but from your description, you want to integrate almost all of the wordpress front end logic.